# How to make 3d effect using gradient android

Tags: android, xml, gradient, effects

I'm trying to add 3d effect as background of `TableRow` using gradient, is there a way to make it appear like a stair 3D effectlike that:

[image: 3d effect stairs]

And wanna my text appear like a box placed on each stair.

Currently i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#77F3AE1B"
        android:centerColor="#77F3AE1B"
        android:endColor="#77AA893C"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <padding android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp" />  
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

but don't look really as 3d effect, i've  try to use image background but have lots of problems bcs of screens dimentions and orientation!